# How do you determine the particular solution to a non-homogeneous DE by undetermined coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked to solve

$y'' +2y' = 2x + 5 -e^{-2x}$

I can find the general solution easily, but the particular solution in this case is hard to find. Here's the answer. I don't know why they got $Ax^2 + Bx + Cxe^{-2x}$

I know the $x$ in $Cxe^{-2x}$ is due to the $e^{-2x}$ being found in the general solution, but I don't know where the $Ax^2 + Bx$ part comes from.

Shouldn't it be $Ax + B + Cxe^{-2x}$, instead?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Ax^2 and Bx, because there is a constant C in the general solution and because of Bx we can't have Ax, so it's Ax^2.